# Number of concurrent connections to GCM service

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

We are sending push notifications to Android devices via GCM API.
People are allowed to subscribe to different topics and receive alert every couple of days.
There is between 100_000 to 1_000_000 users subscribed for given topic, so we wanted to speed things up using more than ten connections.

We see answers with retry, so we retry after specified period of time as stated in the docs.

Can we get rid of retires by using more connections and sending the requests slower?

Or is the quota set for given API key and starting more connections will even hurt us?

EDIT:
We are using GCM HTTP interface. To be precise erlang-gcm library: https://github.com/pdincau/gcm-erlang We are sending message to 1M users. We are not sending to topic. We are performing multicast send to list of users. `gcm-erlang` library allows us to pass 1000 users per request (which is also the limit of GCM API). This means, we have to perform at least 1000 requests.

It takes something around 10 minutes to process all those 1000 requests, so we wanted to make them in parallel, but it doesn't make it faster. Here I've found information on throttling: https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/google/gcm/adv.html#throttling

"Messages are throttled on a per application"

Does it mean, that even if this are messages to different users, we are still throttled, because they are using single API key for our mobile application?

Will the XMPP endpoint faster?

Comment: It's very unclear. Do you send messages to a topic using GCM HTTP interface? What is your problem (given that send to topic is one request)? Why retry, do you get any errors from GCM? Did you consider XMPP interface? Please elaborate.

Comment: @TheWonderBird I edited the question to make it more clear as requested.

Comment: If you are using node.js please have a look at this post may be it can help you https://github.com/ToothlessGear/node-gcm/issues/42

Comment: Also did you get anything or not ??

Answer (score 0):

It is weird that parallelizing requests didn't make them faster. How come? Are you sure that the bottleneck is not on your side?

No, it doesn't look like you're throttled (you would receive errors if you were instead of waiting on line)

I still don't understand why [topics](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/topic-messaging) don't work for you. They seem like a good match.

Anyway, if you want to send messages individually, I would highly recommend switching to [XMPP](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ccs). You will be able to send one hundred messages at a time per connection and open up to 1000 connection (but you're not gonna need that much really).

Comment: It looks like, the bigger number of connections we have, the longer we have to wait for response to the http query. We checked, double checked and then checked again. This queries finish without errors and if we are sending more of them at once concurrently, the response time goes up to 9seconds! We studied the documentation for XMPP endpoint and it looks like it is also throttled.

Comment: @tkowal I'm pretty sure that you aren't facing throttling. Definitely give XMPP a try.